# Data manipulation inside a Phoenix model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

(Coming from the Rails world, I'm now playing with Phoenix, trying to figure out how things work)

Starting from a scaffold, I have a User model containing "first_name" and "last_name" attributes, what I'd like to do now is concatenate them to a "full_name" attribute, in the model, and test it.

Ok, comparing Rails and Phoenix may not be the best thing to do, but let me show how I'd do it with Rails so my question could be perfectly understood:

```
# Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

# Test
it "concatenates first_name and last_name" do
  user = users(:jhondoe)
  assert_equal "jhon doe", user.full_name
end
```

How can I achieve the same kind of thing using Phoenix, and is it even "the way to do it", since I cannot find anything related after hours of intensive googling?

Where and how do I deal with data manipulation using Phoenix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are no methods in Elixir, the recommended way is to create a function in the `User` module for this, and explicitly invoke it whenever you want the full name of a `User`.

```
defmodule YourApp.User do
  ...

  def full_name(%YourApp.User{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}) do
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then, in your tests, templates and/or views, invoke it like:

```
YourApp.User.full_name(user)
```

Sidenote: In Ecto 1.x, it was possible to create a virtual field and add `after_load` callbacks to set its value every time a model was loaded, but callbacks are being removed in Ecto 2.0 (which should be released soon) and so creating a function is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating first and last names must not be the responsibility of the model. You need to design your app and create special modules that would perform such things, some kind of decorators or whatever the right name for those in the functional programming.

But regarding the code, the Dogbert's answer is great.

Comment: Looks like you're right... I'm new to FP/Elixir/Phoenix, and the more I play with it, the more it seems like the "model" is only a sort of DB connector, Data manipulation being processed in external modules. Am I right thinking of it this way?

Comment: @gbarillot I am not sure, and I dont think it has something to do with it being functional language or whatever, it's just common sense, the less responsibility each module has, the more supportable your project will be. If you put everything in your model, you soon will end up with 50 changesets, 100 functions that decorate you last name and 200 functions that update diffrent attributes in different ways. And it's the same with RoR actually.